# Group cohomology of ${\rm SL}_{n}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ acting on trace zero matrices over $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Let $p>5$ be a prime. For any integer $n\geq 2$, let $M_{n}^{0}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ denote the $n\times n$ matrices with trace $0$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ of order $p$. Then we have an action of ${\rm SL}_{n}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ on $M_{n}^{0}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ by conjugation and hence $M_{n}^{0}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is a $\mathbb{F}_p[{\rm SL}_{n}(\mathbb{F}_p)]$-module. Suppose that $p$ does not divide $n$.

In Theorem 3.2 of [A structure theorem for subgroups of GLn over complete local Noetherian rings with large residual image](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.1196), it's proved that the cohomology group $H^{i}({\rm SL}_{n}(\mathbb{F}_p),M_{n}^{0}(\mathbb{F}))$ is always $0$ for $i=1$. Also, it's proved in [2-Cohomologies of the groups SL(n, q)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10469-008-9034-9) that the second cohomology group $H^{2}({\rm SL}_{n}(\mathbb{F}_p),M_{n}^{0}(\mathbb{F}_p))$ is non-zero if and only if $n=2$.

So the question is that: **What do we know about $H^{i}({\rm SL}_{n}(\mathbb{F}_p),M_{n}^{0}(\mathbb{F}_p))$ for $i\geq 3$?**

It would be great if someone could point to relevant literature.

Comment: The stable value (that is, for n big enough with respect to i - an explicit bound of stabilisation is known) should  be easy to deduce from the appendix of Franjou-Friedlander-Scorichenko-Suslin "General linear and functor cohomology over finite fields." (Ann. Math. (2) 150, No. 2, 663-728, 1999), which gives the answer for GL instead of SL.